# I want to set cron job in my linux server (.sh). But I got an error

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl

I want to send email when something happend to my dingtalk messanger, I using this code

```
webhook="https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=xxxxxx";
data=array("msgtype"=>"text","text" => array("content" => $MESSAGE));
data_string=json_encode($data);

ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webhook);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

when I run the file, the output was

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('.  
data=array('msgtype=(text)' 'text=(array('content=($MESSAGE)'))')'
```

it maybe not unix language. I was try for change code into

```
webhook="https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=xxxxxx";
    data=array('msgtype=(text)' 'text=(array('content=($MESSAGE)'))')
    data_string=json_encode($data);

    ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webhook);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
```

this is my full script

```
SITESFILE=sitesweb.txt #list the sites you want to monitor in this file
EMAILS="xxx@xxx.com" #list of email addresses to receive alerts (comma separated)

while read site; do
    if [ ! -z "${site}" ]; then

        CURL=$(curl -s --head $site)

        if echo $CURL | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null
        then
            echo "The HTTP server on ${site} is up!"
        else

            MESSAGE="This is an alert that your site ${site} has failed to respond 200 OK."

            for EMAIL in $(echo $EMAILS | tr "," " "); do
                SUBJECT="$site (http) Failed"
                echo "$MESSAGE" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAIL
                echo $SUBJECT
                echo "Alert sent to $EMAIL"

                webhook="https://oapi.dingtalk.com/robot/send?access_token=xxxxx";
                data=array("msgtype"=>"text","text" => array("content" => $MESSAGE));
                data_string=json_encode($data);

                ch=curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webhook);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_exec($ch);
            done
        fi
    fi
done < $SITESFILE
```

Comment: That code is PHP, not shell script.

Comment: Actually, it's almost PHP. In PHP you need to put `$` before variables when you assign them. E.g. `$webhook = "...";`

Comment: @Barmar do you have any recommendation to fix it?

Comment: Use the `curl` command from the shell, don't try to mix PHP code in a shell script.